# NumberFormatException while converting the data passed from client to server by udp

Tags: java

I have the following code in my client class:

```
private void onCalculateClick() {
    try {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(12346);
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket;
        InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] bytes;

        bytes = aTf.getText().getBytes();
        datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length, local, 12345);
        socket.send(datagramPacket);

        bytes = bTf.getText().getBytes();
        datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length, local, 12345);
        socket.send(datagramPacket);

        bytes = cTf.getText().getBytes();
        datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length, local, 12345);
        socket.send(datagramPacket);

        datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length);
        socket.receive(datagramPacket);

        resultTf.setText(new String(datagramPacket.getData()));
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, here I pass the data from JTextFields to the server and waiting for an answer. By default, the data is 2 in ATF, 8 in bTf and 11 in CTF (maybe it would help). And here's the code of my server:

```
public class UpdServer {
    private double sum1 = 0;
    private double sum2 = 0;
    private byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, 100);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UpdServer();
    }

    private UpdServer() {
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);
            listen();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void listen() {
        int a, b, c;
        try {
            socket.receive(datagramPacket);
            String str = new String(datagramPacket.getData());
            System.out.println(str);
            a = Integer.parseInt(str);

            socket.receive(datagramPacket);
            str = new String(datagramPacket.getData());
            System.out.println(str);
            b = Integer.parseInt(str);

            socket.receive(datagramPacket);
            str = new String(datagramPacket.getData());
            System.out.println(str);
            c = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Thread firstSumThread = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
                    sum1 += (i - 1) * (i - 1);
                }
            });

            Thread secondSumThread = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = b; i < c; i++) {
                    sum2 += (double) 2 * i / (7 * i + 1);
                }
            });

            firstSumThread.start();
            secondSumThread.start();
            firstSumThread.join();
            secondSumThread.join();
            sendBack();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendBack() {
        String str = String.valueOf(sum1 - sum2);
        byte[] send = str.getBytes();
        try {
            datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(send, send.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 12346);
            socket.send(datagramPacket);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the server, client, click on the Calculate button, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2                                                                                                   "
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at com.mikhailovskii.lab2.udp.UpdServer.listen(UpdServer.java:37)
    at com.mikhailovskii.lab2.udp.UpdServer.<init>(UpdServer.java:25)
    at com.mikhailovskii.lab2.udp.UpdServer.main(UpdServer.java:19)
```

So, as I understand, it happens after converting the first passed String to int, but I cannot understand why. so, what's the matter and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your String contains trailing spaces: `"2          "`. Therefore a NumberFormatException happens when trying to convert it to Integer.

You may add the `.trim()` function to your Strings so that leading and trailing spaces are eliminated.

```
String str = new String(datagramPacket.getData());
if (str != null) {
    str = str.trim();
}
a = Integer.parseInt(str);
```